# Pinging the broadcast address shows an IP address is on the network but individual ping says request timeout

Tags: networking, firewall, ping

I pinged a network to find out what devices are on the network via the subnet-broadcast IP address.

```
ping 192.168.0.255
```

A list of IP addresses appeared. Let's suppose that the address `192.168.0.120` appeared from the previous command. However if I now try to ping that address individually I get

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

I would think that if it has anything to do with a firewall (whether it's a network or host firewall) then pinging the subnet-broadcast IP address wouldn't have worked either? Do correct me if I am wrong.

What can cause this?